# Create a column when reading a new file in r

Tags: r, multiple-columns, filenames

I am trying to read multiple files in R and creating a dataframe
What I want is ,whenever I read a new file,I need to create the values as new column instead of row.

The data I have have 2 columns without header and I have 6 files to read.The files are in .txt format.

So after I read the files,I need to have 12 columns.

Please help

Comment: Depends a little how you're looping through the files, but `cbind` in base R or maybe `purrr::map_dfc` would help

Comment: Hi Priya and welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you'd post a small sample of the files you're trying to read.